# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker)

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

Please some one help with this error:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception:
> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pickImage on
> channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker)

I tried almost every possibilities

Comment: In which platform are you testing (android, iOS, linux, windows, web...)?

Comment: flutter dart terminal using flutter run command

Comment: Which platform you are running your code on ? Mobile, windows, Linux, web or macOS ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.